# Label is displayed below the input textbox

Tags: html, css, label

This is my input code sample. So whenever an error is generated, this error label would be visible. But it is coming up below the input element. I want it to be on the right side of the input.

I am able to modify the css for this bit using the label.error code bit I have. Label being the type and error is the class of that label being generated.

```
label.error
{
display:inline;
float:right;
}


> <td><input
> name="answer_engineeringjobs_1^11"
> id="answer_engineeringjobs_1"
> class="reqfield required zipUS error"
> type="text"><label class="error"
> generated="true"
> for="answer_engineeringjobs_1">This
> field is required.</label></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating an element makes it a block, which triggers a new line before it.

You would need to float the input left too.

Comment: floating the element was the problem. Display:inline did the trick!!

Answer (score 1):

Put the `<label>` before your `<input>` element. I know it's strange, but it will probably work.

Edit: wait, maybe you can't alter the order of your tags, in which case this is not very good advice.

Edit some more: You could try adding:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

to your css, so the label won't show up below the textbox anymore. You wouldn't need the `float` code anymore. HOWEVER, all `td`'s would stop wrapping text, which may not be what you want. David's answer may be better.

Comment: Well the label is an error message which is dynamically generated, so putting it before the input element isn't possible.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. I think David's answer would be better in that case. Or maybe put `white-space: nowrap` on the `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

One or the other is a block. If one of them is a block it will cause the elements to stack on top of each other. Either float as David Dorward suggested or set them to display inline

Comment: input, label { display: inline; }  You also don't have to worry about clearing floats

Answer (score 0):

It is actually the parent(s) element(s) size that causes the line break. There's nothing wrong with you code as you can see here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Pc2QB/